# A weird warning with return statement

Tags: java

```
public ResultSet getParticularEmpoyee(int empId){
        PreparedStatement  getParticular;
        ResultSet result;
        try{
             getParticular= conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM "+DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME+" WHERE EMP_ID = ? ");
             getParticular.setInt(1,empId);
             result = getParticular.executeQuery();

            // return result;
        }catch(SQLException e){
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);  
        }
        return result; // this gives the warning that result may not be initialized :)
    }
```

The above is my code for some purpose and i am getting the problem and i can't understand why it is happening :)
will this warning have some serious consequences of its just a warning?
if it is a problem then please tell me the way to avoid this!
if i put return statement in try block then error comes "Return statement missing before last curly brace"

Comment: It's not initialized if a `SQLException` is thrown.

Comment: If an exception is thrown, the local variable `result` may never have been initialized.

Comment: "will this warning have some serious consequences of its just a warning?" It's a compiler error, so yes.

Comment: Pardon me, but apart from technical comment, I seriously don't understand the rational of a smilie :) in a code comment.

Comment: Result may never get initialized because it is initialized within a try block. That should lead to a compile-time warning. I would set it to null when you create the variable, or some value that let's you know if the try block failed.

Comment: By the way, PreparedStatements and ResultSets can be closed when no longer needed. One convenient way to close them can be a try-with-resources block.

Comment: thanks alot 4 helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ResultSet is not initialize, so if there an exception in the try catch, it can be undefined. It's more correct and more clear to initialize to null.

Comment: Alternatively, you could assign the variable to null only in the catch block.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to ask yourself, what happens if an exception is thrown at the start of your `try{}` block. If that *does* happen, then `result` won't be assigned a value, and hence you get that warning.

You need to either assign a 'default' value, or (re)throw an appropriate exception.

Since you're returning a `ResultSet`, you could instead process your results within this method, and that may give you an alternative of returning a null (or perhaps an empty optional) employee.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initiallize all fork of the program's way. Your varible may null without your care.

Put `result = null;` in your catch block.

Best pratice if your variable is effective final, or final. Check this:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4

Answer (score 0):

If the query throws a `SQLException`, the variable `result` has never been assigned a value. What value should it have in this case?

I would suggest that your declare `getParticularEmployee()` to throw the `SQLException`, and let it continue until you reach a method that is UI-specific, like an `Action` set on as a listener on a button.

Keeping low-level implementation free from high-level user interface code allows it to be re-used in more ways. Today, you are creating a desktop application for employee management. Tomorrow, suppose you want to make some of its functionality available through a web service. Separating the logic from the presentation layer will allow you to build a new front end, but reuse all the logic on the back end.

You also have a problem with resources. The `PreparedStatement` should be closed, but you lose track of it when your method returns. Also, it can't be closed before you are finished using the `ResultSet`.